# WCF and NoSql best practice

Tags: mongodb, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services, nosql

I want to use WCF and Nosql together,anyone can suggest some best practice

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [blog post](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2083-how-to-visualize-an-azure-table-in-excel-using-odata/) shows how you can take a NoSQL Azure storage table and expose it as an OData feed.